# Crossrider.com - IE add-on not working when run as admin?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, windows-xp, windows-installer, crossrider, browser-addons

This is regarding the web browser add-ons created with [Crossrider.com](http://crossrider.com/). I have created an installer from that site to install an Internet Explorer add-on.

When I run a crossrider created "Internet Explorer 8" add-on installer, it works fine and shows the icon in the Internet Explorer 8's toolbar. This is in Windows XP. But when I run the installer as admin (*Right-click > Run as > select the username*) it is not showing the icon or working. But it is still shows as enabled in the "Managed Add-ons" dialog. What can be the issue here?

This only happens in Windows XP. For the new versions of Windows, run as admin works fine.

Comment: Thank you for reporting the issue. I have reproduced it and escalated it to the dev team to investigate. I suggest monitoring our [Changelog](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/guide/changelog) for an update as to when it's fixed though it may take a while as the dev team are working on many projects. [**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help **Shlomo**. I figured out the issue. It is not with *run as admin* it seems. I have bundled the crossrider created installer in another main installer. This will extract the IE installer and run it. I assumed since the main installer is running as admin, the issue was related to that but it's not.

This seems to be the issue here. When the installer is bundled with the main installer and extracted again it is producing the issue explained in the question above. Whether it was run by the main installer or opened by double-clicking it, same issue.

So in order to come across this I compressed the crossrider created installer to a ZIP file. Then include it in the main installer. Main installer will extract the zip file and run the IE installer inside. This way it works and prevents the issue mentioned in the question above.

It seems when the IE installer executable is bundled directly (as EXE file) with another executable and extracted again it is not working correctly.

So when the crossrider created installer exe is added inside another exe file. Then extracted and run, it it not showing the toolbar in IE or working at all although it shows in the "Manage Add-ons" dialog as installed and enabled. But when the crossrider created installer exe is compressed into a zip file and added inside another exe file, then extracted and run; this way it is showing the toolbar icon and working.

This is only in Windows XP Internet Explorer 8.